# Byte position in Java

Tags: java, byte

I have searched some time about this matter and didn't find proper answer anywhere.

Let's say I have a string:

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

I need to find unique words in this string and their **byte positions** and also **byte distance** between same words.

Ok I can manage to find words, but what is their byte position and any ideas to track distance in bytes? Is for example: 5 is the position of string *quick* and converted to bytes?

I hope this doesn't sound too stupid (I am fairly new to Java).

Comment: Have you written any code to achieve this yet? Or even psuedo code? Any effort at all?

Comment: How is this string encoded ?

Comment: @PeterMmm has a good point, a letter is not necessarily one byte long, and it also depends on the encoding, for instance, the character ñ encoded in UTF-8 occupies two bytes

Comment: @takendark As I said in the example, I can find position in string with _indexOf_ Let's assume it's UTF-8.

Comment: Assumptions while programming are horrible. Don't do it. Also, that has nothing to do with any code you wrote to find byte position which is what I'm asking about.

Comment: `indexOf()` only gives you a "logical" distance inside the String object, it is not actually the distance in bytes from the beginning of the String

Comment: use string.getBytes() method to convert string to byete array

Comment: @morgano that is what I am asking, what is distance in bytes?

Comment: @Takendarkk I didn't write any code because I don't understand **byte position**.

Comment: Try with `ByteArrayInputStream stream=new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes());`

Comment: @skywalker you should by now have gotten the message that "byte position" of a letter or word in a Java String is not a useful concept.

Comment: ok, just for you to have it a bit more clear, try this code: `String myString = "año"; System.out.println(">>" + myString.getBytes().length);` it won't print 3 but 4, and if you try to calculate the "byte distance" between "a" and "o", it would give you 2, Is that what you want?

Comment: @morgano wouldn't the distance then depend on which encoding you use for `getBytes`?

Comment: @morgano It will but only with `getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` it prints 4. I understand that. That is probably byte distance, right?

Comment: @user3580294 exactly, that's my point from the beginning, that's why @PeterMmm asked about the encoding, there is not much sense talking about byte distance unless you have very clear that it depends on the encoding, and, let me point out again, `indexof()` doesn't give you the byte position

Comment: @skywalker yes, if you are going to work with, say, only ASCII chars just convert to byte[] from the beginning ('getBytes("ASCII")') and forget about Strings and `indexOf()`

Comment: @skywalker What are you trying to do that requires you to know the precise byte position/distance for characters in a string?

Comment: @user3580294 I was given an assignment (on a job interview) to do this: upload text file through browser, find unique words in that file, their byte positions/distances, and more stuff in there as well, but that is the essence of that task.

Comment: It seems to me at least that without specifying encoding it's a rather ill-defined question in that you can't give a precise answer, but it might be possible to give a general solution that would give the byte positions/distances for a arbitrary encoding.

Comment: @user3580294 They did specify one thing though, text file for testing is from [here](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2345.txt)

Comment: I suppose your best bet at this point is to either ask for encoding straight off the bat or assume one encoding but provide the option to specify another, because it seems that even plain text files can have different encodings and encoding detection isn't a perfectly solvable problem...

Comment: Agree with @user3580294, maybe they are even waiting for you to ask about the encoding

Comment: ok guys thanks for your time and effort, I will ask them for some clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding unique words should be fairly easy; split on whitespace, add strings to a `Set`, and whatever's in the `Set` at the end of the method will be the unique words in the file. this can be made arbitrary complex though, depending on what defines a unique word, and if characters other than whitespace separate words.

The byte position/distance question is a bit harder. If memory serves, `String` objects in Java are wrappers around `char[]` objects, and `chars` are 16-bit unicode characters in Java (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

So I'm guessing byte distance is just a linear function of the character position?

If you're working with other encodings though the `getBytes()` method might be useful.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html

So for something like that, a naive solution would be to determine the number of bytes for each character, which would allow for really easy calculation of byte positions/distances, but determining that probably isn't that efficient. It should, however, yield correct results if done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Positions are counted from 0, not 1. So "quick" would have character position 5, which for US-ASCII is also the byte position. Maybe character positions suffice.

```
String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
int charsIndex = s.indexOf("quick"); // 4
int charsLength = "The ".length(); // 4
int bytesLength = "The ".getBytes("UTF-8").length; // 4
char ch = s.charAt(4); // 'q'
int c = s.codePointAt(4); // (int) 'q'
```

In Java text (`String`) is always in Unicode, hence all chars are possible and combinable.
Bytes (`byte[]`) are in some *encoding* and may vary per encoding.